# C++ dependency injection with hypodermic: "resolve" Objects of a super-type

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, hypodermic

given the following class hierarchy:

```
class AbstractPanel
{ }

class AbstractComponent : public AbstractPanel
{ }

class Component : public AbstractComponent
{ }
```

and the following Hypodermic DI Container:

```
Hypodermic::ContainerBuilder builder;
builder.registerType<Component>( CREATE(new Component()) )->as<Component>()->named<Component>("bkgrd_param_component");
(... and adding it to "di_container")
```

Depending on the Context, a resolve()-Call looks like this:

```
di_container->resolveNamed<AbstractComponent>("bkgrd_param_component")
```

or

```
di_container->resolveNamed<AbstractPanel>("bkgrd_param_component")
```

Both calls return a nullptr, although my registered Object is both of type "AbstractPanel" and "AbstractComponent".

How do I have to design this?
I can't change the class-hierarchy but want to resolve the Object, depending on its name.

Does anybody have an idea?

Regards, Vandahlen

Answer (score 0):

Although your `Component` is an `AbstractComponent` and an `AbstractPanel`, *Hypodermic* isn't aware of that, that is, you have to tell it yourself.

```
ContainerBuilder builder;

builder.registerType< Component >(CREATE(new Component()))
       ->named< AbstractComponent >("bkgrd_param_component")
       ->named< AbstractPanel >("bkgrd_param_component");
```

That way, `Component` is known as both `AbstractComponent` and `AbstractPanel` *named* "bkgrd_param_component" and the resolutions you gave:

`container->resolveNamed< AbstractComponent >("bkgrd_param_component")`

and

`container->resolveNamed< AbstractPanel >("bkgrd_param_component")`

will provide *two different* instances of the type `Component`.

There is a new non-intrusive version of *Hypodermic* you could use. The Dsl is a bit more elegant:

```
ContainerBuilder builder;

builder.registerType< Component >()
       .named< AbstractComponent >("bkgrd_param_component")
       .named< AbstractPanel >("bkgrd_param_component");
```

Have a look at its [wiki](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic/wiki).